# How do I convert this multi-file .xsd into one or more classes?

Tags: .net, xsd

on [this](http://portal.wko.at/wk/format_detail.wk?angid=1&stid=598785&dstid=9378&opennavid=52016) website, there is the invoice.xsd for electronic invoices. It references several other xsd files, all of which can be found directly below it.

I have tried downloading them and using the xsd.exe command line tool, and I have tried using a parameter file to include the multiple files, but nothing worked. What do I have to do to get the complete structure as .net classes?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "nothing worked"; is this to say that you were not able to successfully generate classes? Did you get warnings? Or were some classes not showing up as expected by you?

Comment: @PetruGardea Thanks, but I already figured it out. There is some problem with the reference to dsig:signature in the invoice.xsd. I removed the property and now I can generate the cs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling xsd.exe and passing in the list of xsd files?

eg `xsd /c schema1.xsd schema2.xsd schema3.xsd`

If you only pass in a single schema you'll only get the CS generated for those types.